# Best practice when changing minSdkVersion from 10 to 14

Tags: android, android-fragments

Since Android OS is too fragmented, we have to support minSdkVersion=10. But considering api level 10, 11 are too few and hard to maintain now, we decided to move to 14+. What is the best practice when changing minSdkVersion up?

We're using Fragment, ActionBarCompat in the support v4 library. Should we get rid of these classes (that may save us hundreds KB of apk size)? Or should we continue using them?

Comment: Always is better to use component from app-compact because when some issue will be founded in app-compact there is to easy to fix it than in Android SDK

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak thanks, so why's not let it be an answer instead of voting the question down? The question is about best practice when changing minSdkVersion up but not about trying to convince everyone to not using support v4 library. Don't you agree?

Comment: I can put my answer as post if you want. I didn't downvote your question. For me it is very interesting question and I give you upvote for this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend you to get rid of support fragments. I tried this before and as result i spent a lot of time for nothing... 
For example useful method `getChildFragmentManager()` available only for >= 16 api lvl. My recommendation is to always use support v4 lib and Support Fragments instead of usual Fragments.

Now about ActionBar - my recommendation is get rid of the awful thing. Replace it with new component [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html).

Don't worry about a few hundreds kbs

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, always is better to use component from app-compact because when some issue will be founded in app-compact there is to easy to fix it than in Android SDK. Additionally new app-compact library are are often updated and fixed than Android SDK.